# Django admin import-export one model and two different csv files depending select options?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export, and want to import to one model different CSV files. I mean for example I have a model Statement

```
class Statement(models.Model):
    amount = MoneyField(max_digits=14,
                        decimal_places=4,
                        default_currency='EUR',
                        currency_field_name='currency',
                        default="0.0000",
                        currency_max_length=5,
                        null=True
                        )
    type = models.CharField(name='type', choices=Type.choices, max_length=50, default=Type.INCOME)
```

But I want to import statement files from different bank accounts, and, of course, the structure of each file can be different.

One bank has CSV like

```
ref_code, amount, currency, direction
1569852, 10.00, EUR, Income
```

The second bank has a structure

```
Order number, Amount, Curr, Account No
569486, 10.99, EUR, BE658954412
```

But I want to import this data, parse and insert it into the same table.

I created a Resource class, Custom Import Form, etc.

```
class StatementResource(resources.ModelResource):
     amount = Field(attribute='amount', column_name='Amount')
     currency = Field(attribute='currency', column_name='Currency')

     class Meta:
        model = Statement
     ...
```

```
class CustomImportForm(ImportForm):
    bank = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        to_field_name='pk',
        queryset=Bank.objects.all(),
        required=True)
```

Then I rewrite get_import_data_kwargs

```
@admin.register(Statement)
class StatementAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = StatementResource

    def get_import_form(self):
        return CustomImportForm

    def get_import_data_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = kwargs.get('form')
        if form:
            return {"bank": form.cleaned_data["bank"]}
        return dict()
```

But how to parse CSV depending on which bank is selected?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [v3](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/3.0.0b4/) of django-import-export.

You need to define two resources for the same model:

```py
class Statement1Resource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Statement
        fields = ['ref_code', 'amount', 'currency', 'direction']
        

class Statement2Resource(ModelResource):
     amount = Field(attribute='amount', column_name='Amount')
     currency = Field(attribute='currency', column_name='Currency')

    class Meta:
        model = Statement
        fields = [] # declare fields as required
```

Then you need to declare these in your Admin class:

```py
class StatementAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [Statement1Resource, Statement2Resource]
```

This means that when you import, you can choose which Resource declaration you want to use for the import, for example (taken from example application):

[image]